# how to display image description written by user in django template

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I am a newbie in Django.I want to create simple upload app in which description of image ,price and email-id will be entered by the user.And want to display the description text and email along with the image.But the text is not appearing along with the image.
[See the final image after uploading](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ndFgH.png)

Below is my code :

**Models.py**

```
  # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from django.db import models

class Document(models.Model):

    docfile = models.FileField(upload_to='documents/%Y/%m/%d')

    description = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)

    price = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    emailId = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)



**forms.py**

    from django import forms


class DocumentForm(forms.Form):

    docfile = forms.FileField(
        label='Select a file',
    )
    description = forms.CharField(max_length=255)

    price = forms.IntegerField()

    emailId = forms.CharField(max_length=255) 

**views.py**

from django.template import RequestContext

from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect

from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

from django.shortcuts import render

from django.shortcuts import render_to_response

from myapp.models import Document

from myapp.forms import DocumentForm

def list(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':

        form = DocumentForm(request.POST, request.FILES)

        if form.is_valid():

            newdoc = Document(docfile = request.FILES['docfile'])

            newdoc.save()


            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('list'))
    else:
        form = DocumentForm() # A empty, unbound form


    documents = Document.objects.all()


    return render(request,'myapp/list.html',{'documents': documents, 'form': form} )

def index(request):

    return render_to_response('myapp/index1.html')

**list.html**

{% load staticfiles %}

{% load static %}

<html>

  <head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <title>Recent Uploads</title>

  </head>
  <body>

    <form action="{% url "list" %}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <button type="submit">Upload</button>
</form>

    <div id="wrapper">
      <section>
        {% if documents %}
        <ul id="gallery">
          {% for document in documents %}
          <li>
             <a href="{{ document.docfile.url }}">
              <img src="{{ document.docfile.url }}" alt=""></a>
              <p>
                <font color="black"> 
                  <p>Description : {{ document.description }}</p>
                  <p>Price :{{ document.price }}</p>
                  <p>Contact/Email-ID : {{ document.emailId }}</p>
            </font>
            </a>
          </li>
          {% endfor %}
        </ul>
        {% else %}
            <p>No documents.</p>
        {% endif %}
      </section>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your form and code is perfectly correct although description and eMailid is null in your database. Check in the documents object.

Answer (score 0):

Your form does not save data to the database. You need to inherit from `forms.ModelForm` rather than `forms.Form`. For the latter, you may require to write your own custom save method. `ModelForms` does that for you implicitly.

forms.py,

```
class DocumentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Document
        fields = "__all__"
```

views.py,

```
def list(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = DocumentForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            doc = form.save(commit=False)
            doc.docfile = request.FILES['docfile']
            doc.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('list'))
    else:
        form = DocumentForm() 
    documents = Document.objects.all()
    return render(request,'myapp/list.html',{'documents': documents, 'form': form} )
```

Comment: thank you for your help! I tried this but this time image is not displaying but other than that its fine.

Comment: Edited my answer. Please do give it a try!